# How to get data to work when used within a component and Axios?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I'm new to `Vue.js` and `Axios`. I don't quite understand how to get the `data` option to work when used within a component.

**Why doesnt' my test work?**

I get the following error in the console:

> ```
> [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
>
> [Vue warn]: Property or method "symbols" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)
> ```

My simple test:

**My data** (snipped for brevity):

```js
[{"id":1, "name": "Airfield"}, {"id":2, "name": "Ship Yard"}]
```

**My component:**

```js
Vue.component('symbols-table', {
    template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>',
    data: {
        symbols: []
     },
     created: function(){
         axios.get('symbols.json').then(response => this.symbols = response.data);
      }
});
```

**Vue instance**:

```js
var app = new Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

**My HTML**:

```html
<symbols-table>
    <ul><li v-for="symbol in symbols">{{symbol.name}}</li></ul>
</symbols-table>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As the error is saying:

> The "data" option should be a function

In the component, the [*data must be a function*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function), you need to modify the data block to be a function which will return the data structure to be used in DOM in a reactive way:

```js
Vue.component('symbols-table', {
    template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>',
    data: function() {
         return  {
           symbols: []
         }
    },
    created: function(){
        axios.get('symbols.json').then(response => this.symbols = response.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, that was one of the issues...and I should have known that. However, I still get the following error in console: "Property or method "symbols" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render....snip.." . My code looks the same above but with the added data function mentioned. Any ideas?

Comment: @redshift the problome is you have `symbols` at child level, however you are using it at DOM on parent level.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Comment: Saving tip, I was copying and pasting from the original router-less version and I forgot this detail even though it's mentioned clearly in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`data` inside a Vue Component should be a function that returns an object, as described in [the Vue.js common gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-does-data-need-to-be-a-function).

Answer (score 4):

You can type simply like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        ...... tra-ta-ta.......
    }
},
```